# How to Implement AngularJS JWT Authentication for Java Spring REST API

Tags: java, angularjs, spring, jwt

I want to Implement locally user management for my application. for back-end I use java spring REST.I don't use cloud user management service like `Auth0` or `UserApp`. Because of some feature I want to use `JWT` method for user authentication and authorization, But I do not see how should I implement it in Java and the AngularJS?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I did a talk about how to add authentication with JWTs to an AngularJS app.

You can see it here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lDb_GANDR8U

The code for that presentation is in here: https://github.com/auth0/angularjs-jwt-authentication-tutorial

In that example, the server is NodeJS. If you need Java, you can do something similar to https://github.com/auth0/spring-security-auth0/tree/master/examples/spring-boot-api-example. That example is for Auth0, but the JWT validation applies to your case as well :), since it's generic.

Let me know if this helps.

Cheers!

Comment: Is auth0 free to use for commercial purposes?

Comment: Hi mgonto...How do I send the token to backend?

Answer (score 1):

Try [satellizer](https://github.com/sahat/satellizer). They provide Java server implementation in the exemple folder.
Check it

Comment: this example base on java core , I m searching for Spring Freamwork

Answer (score -2):

Although this could seem complex, it will be very useful for you to take a look at [Stormpath](http://stormpath.com). We have a quite a straightforward solution for this. Please take a look at [Using Stormpath for API Authentication](http://docs.stormpath.com/guides/api-key-management/).

As a summary, your solution will look like this:

1. You will use the [Stormpath Java SDK](https://github.com/stormpath/stormpath-sdk-java) to easily delegate all your user-management needs.
2. When the user presses the login button, your front end will send the credentials securely to your backend-end through its REST API.

   2.1. By the way, Stormpath greatly enhances all the possibilities here. Instead of having your own login page, you can completely delegate the login/register functionality to Stormpath via its [IDSite](http://docs.stormpath.com/guides/using-id-site/), or you can also delegate it to our [Servlet Plugin](https://docs.stormpath.com/java/servlet-plugin/login.html). Stormpath also supports Google, Facebook, LinkedIn and Github login.
3. Your backend will then try to authenticate the user against the Stormpath Backend and will return an `access token` as a result:

   ```
   /** This code will throw an Exception if the authentication fails */
   public void postOAuthToken(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
       Application application = client.getResource(applicationRestUrl, Application.class);

       //Getting the authentication result
       AccessTokenResult result = (AccessTokenResult) application.authenticateApiRequest(request);

       //Here you can get all the user data stored in Stormpath
       Account account = accessTokenResult.getAccount();

       response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_OK);
       response.setContentType("application/json");

       //Output the json of the Access Token
       response.getWriter().print(token.toJson());
       response.getWriter().flush();
   }
   ```
4. Then, for every authenticated request, your backend will do:

   ```
   public void getEquipment(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
       Application application = client.getResource(applicationRestUrl, Application.class);

       OauthAuthenticationResult result = (OauthAuthenticationResult) application.authenticateOauthRequest(request).execute();

       System.out.println(result.getApiKey());
       System.out.println(result.getAccount());

       //Return what you need to return in the response
       handleEquipmentRequest(response);
   }
   ```

Please take a look [here](http://docs.stormpath.com/guides/api-key-management/#exchanging-api-keys-for-oauth-20-tokens) for more information

Hope that helps!

Disclaimer, I am an active Stormpath contributor.